# Can I log Hours in a foreign aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging, ppl

I have my FAA Private Pilot License but I live in Chile, The thing is that I was asked by the father of a friend of mine to join him on a C182 flight in Chile (Chilean Aircraft). So, can I log  that time in my Log Book? Even though I did my training in a C172 and don’t have the High Performance endorsement?

Comment: If it is a Chilean-registered aircraft you will most likely need to hold a Chilean licence to fly there.

Comment: The rule of 3 apply I think, if it was an american registred aircraft in Chile you can, if it was a chilean registred aircraft in US you can. But you don't seem to have 2 out of 3. So it will be a no I think.

Comment: Aside from the foreign location, it's a single pilot airplane and as such, you're going along for a ride and shouldn't be logging time, unless the owner is a flight instructor and you can log time as P2, or unless the owner is designating you PIC, in which case you'd better be on his insurance.